# Displaying the your input at the next page

Tags: html, forms, input, field

currently I had written a html page for a form submission. How do I go about bring all the inputs the user written on my submit button to another html page that display all the input.

Comment: Which Server Side Language are you using?

Comment: At a high level: On the server side, validate the form input, store it in a database, then finally redirect to another page which renders the stored input from the form.

Comment: Hi guys, I don't have a server side. I'm still new to this. Does it mean that I need to store the information that the user input in the database and than call it out from there? Is it possible to do it without storing it in a database?

Comment: Yes you can do it without storing your input in a database but you need to use a Server Side Language like for example PHP. Manual for PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/

Comment: Yeah thanks guys. got it working using PHP. the $POST function and echo my results out in another page.